# Is there an open-source project that provides centralized package information for Linux server farms?

Tags: package-management

I manage large server farms running centos, ubuntu, and debian operating systems. I want to have a centralized service that knows all the servers and the packages installed on them. I use puppet to declare if specific packages need to be installed. I use dnf-automatic in redhat-based systems and unattended-upgrades in Debian-based systems to maintain automatic updates. These systems work well, but they do not provide centralized reporting for all packages for all systems. I want to be able to answer questions like the following (at any given time):

How many and which systems are running kernel version 5? What systems have old versions of nginx installed?

I know dnf-automatic provides an emitter option that allows me to run a command after updates. I could create my own central db and schema, then build custom scripts that list all rpms and send their metadata to a centralized server. Is there something that already does this?

I know puppet/puppetdb has this functionality, but it is only for puppet enterprise (my company can’t/won’t give me a budget for enterprise software).

Comment: Take a look at foreman, in particular as it hooks into Puppet, which you already have, pretty well. https://www.theforeman.org/introduction.html